# Sharing Files on iOS using the Files App from Xamarin

Tags: ios, xamarin

Hello I want to have medium sized Files that one Xamarin app or Xamarin.UITest write and are consumed by yet another App. iOS 11+ can be assumed

I am thinking the logical way to do this is the iOS files App.

I have looked for how to interface with the Files App and have not seen anything

Thanks,
Mark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having a look at this document, **[Sharing with the Files app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/file-system#sharing-with-the-files-app)** :

iOS 11 introduced the **Files** app - a file browser for iOS that allows the user to see and interact with their files in iCloud and also stored by any application that supports it. To allow the user to directly access files in your app, create a new boolean key in the **Info.plist** file `LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace` and set it to true, as here:

[image]

The app's **Documents** directory will now be available for browsing in the **Files** app. In the **Files** app, navigate to On My iPhone and each app with shared files will be visible. The screenshots below show what the [FileSystem sample app](https://learn.microsoft.com/samples/xamarin/ios-samples/filesystemsamplecode) looks like:

[image][image]

Comment: As of July 2020, "Supports Document Browser" seems to be the key you want to add to the plist to make files show up in the Files app.

Comment: @jgfооt Thanks , you're right . From July 2020 , we need to modify that . https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/view_controllers/adding_a_document_browser_to_your_app/setting_up_a_document_browser_app

Comment: Will setting LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace in 1st app allow a 2nd app to read Documents directory within 1st app?  Specifically, I want my 2nd app (Xcode Obj-C) to read files from my 1st app (Xamarin.IOS) -- is this possible?